Angular Universal lifecycle with standalone components, when are network values cached and when is it safe to retrieve on client side?
I'm an Angular veteran, but am fairly new to Angular Universal and my Google / ChatGPT abilities seem to have failed me. I can't seem to find anywhere in the docs. I want to know exactly when values fetched from network on the server side are safe to read client side and what the lifecycle is. I would love it if the Angular team made some kind of flow chart, or if there is one, I could see it.
I'm running off of a lot of assumptions, more than I'm comfortable with as I feel like I'm most likely incorrect. I also heard that standalone components won't work the way I'm thinking but then other people say it will work.
Let me explain my understanding and you can tell me if/where I'm wrong. I got my information from the docs here and from reading around forums and such.

User makes a request to the web site https://potato.org/123.
This request gets sent to the server function, it prerenders the initial state of the page they request.
(Here's the fuzzy part and it's a huge assumption) The page is looked up in the router, the PotatoComponent is found, ngOnInit is called by Angular. If a request to get the potato with ID 123 is made using the HttpClient during OnInit it knows to cache this and won't forward the initial state of the app to the user until success or error of any/all network calls made in OnInit.
Forward the request to the client side.
Client side gets Hydrated from what was rendered server side and the request response was cached in the HttpClient, when the client side ngOnInit makes the network request it instantly returns with the cached value.

Or, from reading around, there's an alternative

The server side can put the potato with ID 123 in a TransferState object before forwarding to the client side.
The client can check if there's a cached value instead of doing a network call.

Here's my expectation for the alternate, TransferState way:
import { inject, makeStateKey, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { TransferState } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';

@Component({ ... Assume all the right stuff is in here ... })
class PotatoPageComponent implements OnInit {
  private transferState = inject(TransferState);
  private platformId = inject(PLATFORM_ID);
  private potato: Potato | null = null;

  ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    // assume the ID was retrieved from the route info
    const POTATO_TRANSFER_KEY = makeStateKey('potato|123');

    this.potato = this.transferState.get(
      POTATO_TRANSFER_KEY,
      null
    );
    if (this.potato === null) {
      // potato service uses fetch api
      this.potato = await this.potatoService.getPotato(123);
      if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
        this.transferState.set(POTATO_TRANSFER_KEY, this.potato);
      }
    }
  }
}

and the server side won't forward until ngOnInit completes? Does Angular do something like this:
await component.ngOnInit();

// Forward to client side

If that is the case, is it technically ok to use the fetch system and bypass HttpClient completely as long as you await properly in ngOnInit?
I ran a little test and it seemed like it does not properly await like I was expecting but I'm not confident in that finding, I feel like it may be awaiting but I'm new and not quite sure.
If fetch is just simply not an option, am I safe to assume any network call started in ngOnInit using HttpClient WILL finish before forwarding to the client side? I'm not even sure if ngOnInit is the correct place and maybe it's only requests started in the constructor? Is there a different lifecycle hook I should be using?
Or is Angular doing something more like this?
component.ngOnInit(); // Or some other lifecycle hook

await HttpClient.finishNetworkCalls() and do interceptor things

// Forward to client side


I am using Firebase hosting in my setup, when I used firebase init it set up SSR hosting automatically and auto-generated the server side function and all that. I am also using completely standalone components. No module files.
Please don't answer by simply telling me not to use fetch with no other context, I am trying to understand the underlying technology, not get instructions on what I'm doing wrong. I'm perfectly happy to use HttpClient, I've used it in other projects that don't use the newer, standalone components.

I tried the code provided above using the fetch api on my staging server but Discord did not properly have the title and meta description tags I set after retrieving the potato. These exact title and meta tags work if I manually set them to some arbitrary value at the start of ngOnInit. I assume the fetch approach did not work and we MUST use HttpClient. But I want to understand the lifecycle a little better.
(I don't own potato.org, I want to keep my site private, if that wasn't aparant).

To answer part of your question, httpclient returns an Observable.  You can subscribe to it and when it's done your subscription gets the results.  Angular is always checking for changes in your "model"... those are just basically arrays/values in your "controller" (.ts file).  So when the results do appear at some point in the future you will probably take the results and update the "model" in the controller. Angular will update any components that are tied to the "model" or "state" in your view/template (.html file)  More on observables here: https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular

SSR/non-SSR is another concern.  The basics of how things work is the same...

Yeah that doesn't remotely answer my questions about the lifecycle between server render then sending to the client side, which is all I'm interested in. I want to know how the system works. I know how observables work and I will probably swap over to them, but I still want to understand the lifecycle.

It seems like you have several questions in one here. I would suggest that you consider the following: What happens if ngOnInit returns an Observable? As Angular has Promise based APIs, like the router navigation methods, so what is the difference between await p and return p.then(() => {})? What is ZoneJS? (hint: It is something evil)

It seems like I have multiple questions in one, but I really don't. I want an explanation of the lifecycle without any fuzzy answers so I know exactly when and what values are stored on the server side, exactly when the handoff to the client side happens, and what values are safe to assume will exist on the client side after the hand off.

It might help you to understand when using SSR.
When a request arrives on your server that hosts your Angular SSR App, it will render the requested page as It will do on a browser, but using "CommonEngine".
I think the server will wait for your components to be rendered, but I am not sure it will wait for services that makes http requests that are not blocking the component rendering.
If your app makes requests with HttpClient or fetch, you can store the result with TransferState TransferState->set.
And all data that you have stored with TransferState will be passed to the Client.
If you inspect the source code of the rendered page, their is a script tag like:
<script id="serverApp-state" type="application/json">{"1853067340":{"b":[{"id":"89","title":"Guide des meilleurs compléments alimentaire

This data can be retrieved from the client, but you have to check if the data are stored, otherwise you need to make a request.
When the client app load, it will rerender all the app (not totally true since the partial hydratation).
And all component lifecycles will be executed "again".
So to avoid making an useless API call, you need to check if the data are stored with TransferState.
Example (The code is a little bit old, but is works, It might be updated):
I hope it will help you :D
My ArticlesComponents call ArticlesService to get the articles to display:
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ArticlesService {
  ...
  getAllArticles() {
    const url = environment.serverConfig.serverURL + `?method=getArticles`;
    return this.transferStateService.getData(url, null, () => {
      return this.http.get<Array<Article>>(url)
        .pipe(
          catchError(this.handleError)
        );
    });
  }
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TransferStateService {

  constructor(private transferHttp: TransferState) { }

  getData(url, options, callback: () => Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
    const optionsString = options ? JSON.stringify(options) : '';
    let key = `${url + optionsString}`;
    try {
      return this.resolveData(key);
    } catch (e) {
      return callback()
        .pipe(tap((data) => {
          this.setCache(key, data);
        }))
    }
  }

  private resolveData(key) {
    let resultData: any;
    if (this.hasKey(key)) {
      resultData = this.getFromCache(key);
    } else {
      throw new Error()
    }
    return of(resultData);
  }

  private setCache(key, value) {
    this.transferHttp.set(key, value)
  }
  private getFromCache(key) {
    return this.transferHttp.get(key, null) // null set as default value
  }
  private hasKey(key) {
    return this.transferHttp.hasKey(key)
  }
}


This doesn't answer my concerns.
"I think the server will wait for your components to be rendered, but I am not sure it will wait for services that makes http requests that are not blocking the component rendering."
This is exactly the part I'm fuzzy on. You have basically repeated my assumptions without illuminating anything about the part I am unsure of about the lifecycle and exactly when the handoff happens.
